# List files in sdcard returns Null

Tags: android, file-listing

I'm working on modifying Android framework and trying to add a module to check files in sdcard as follows:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "new");
dir.mkdirs();

File list[] = dir.listFiles();

for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
{
    myList.add( list[i].getName() );
}
```

Null exception happens in listing files of sdcard. Why does this null exception happen?
Existing solution in SO is froam Android application perspective, which can be resolved by adding permission. But from the framework perspective, what could be the solution? Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean form the "framework perspective"?

Comment: I'm not working on Android application. I'm trying to instrument Android OS itself.

Comment: Only execute the for loop if list!=null. list can be null.

Comment: First you should only execute mkdirs() if the directory does not exists. Second you should also check the return value of dir.mkdirs() and not continue if it fails. `I'm working on modifying Android framework`. I would fire you directly. You make basic beginner errors. Congratulations that you got this job though.

Answer (score -1):

The

```
dir.mkdirs();
```

creates the directory named by this file, creating missing parent directories if necessary.

By default this directory is empty until you write some file.

Also make sure you have the permission to write to the extenral drive. Put this permission in your application's manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is that I don't know how to add permission since I'm working on instrumenting Android OS itself, not an application.

Comment: what is instrumenting Android OS?

Comment: I'm trying to change some classes of Android framework v4.4.4.

Comment: Every application in the AOSP has a  manifest file. There you put the persmissions